# Android Navigation Component with Drawer Layout and Dynamic Menu Items

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, drawerlayout, android-navigation-graph

So, here is what I want.

The top level data is structured like below :

```
Section 1 Title -> Section 1 Content (List)
Section 2 Title -> Section 2 Content (List)
.
.
.
Section N Title -> Section N Content (List)
```

I want to display the section titles in the side menu which opens when the hamburger is icon is selected and when a specific section is selected, the side menu closes and the content for that section is loaded in the screen under the action bar.

So, the relevant UI components to be used are : `Toolbar`, `DrawerLayout` (for Side Menu) and `Fragment` for loading the content in the center.

Now, I am trying to use the [Navigation Components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) and get as much benefits of it as possible. The thing that I am unable to get to work is :

1. Loading dynamic items in the side menu. The examples show using the `android menu resources`. I would like to use my own recycler view and load the menu dynamically.
2. How to define the navGraph for a data structure like this. I tried to create an action from the `ContentFragment` to itself but I wasn't sure this was right because, there is no action inside it that takes the UI from one `ContentFragment` to another `ContentFragment`. It is a top level action from the side menu that loads a different `ContentFragment`.

Apart from the above 2 questions, I want to know if this is even a right candidate for using navigation components or is it better to use the traditional approach?

Comment: I have a clean solution for you and here is the full source: https://github.com/dautovicharis/sos_android/tree/q_68441622

Let me know how it looks. Thanks

Comment: Additional here is video: https://streamable.com/ovpcwf

Comment: @HarisDautović : In any case, could you drop an answer below? I cannot accept or give you the bounty if you just leave a comment.

Comment: In the video, could you show the back operations as well? It is expected to take the user back to the previous fragment.

Comment: I'll add an answer, but I wanted your confirmation first that this is what you are looking for.  The back button just closes the app. Maybe you have missed my first comment, but there is a full source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing this is easily done with AndroidNavigation components.

**1 - Dynamic DrawerLayout can be implemented by adding RecyclerView inside** `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

**2 - Activity navigation init when using DrawerLayout**

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(R.id.mainFragment),
    binding.drawerLayout
)

binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

// Setup action bar with nav controller
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

**3 - `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView` init**

```
private fun loadDrawerItems(items: Array<String>) {
        binding.rvDrawer.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = DrawerAdapter(items, this@MainActivity)
        }
    }
```

**4 - DrawerAdapter notify activity when the user clicks on the item**

```
 override fun onDrawerItemClick(value: String) {
        binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        val direction = NavGraphDirections.refreshMainFragment(value)
        navController.navigate(direction)
    }
```

**5 - Navigation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="dh.sos.MainFragment"
        android:label="Main fragment">
        <argument
            android:name="value"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="Default value"/>


    </fragment>

    <action android:id="@+id/refreshMainFragment"
        app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true">

        <argument
            android:name="value"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="Default value"/>
    </action>
</navigation>
```

`app:popUpToInclusive="true"` indicates that `popUpTo` destination should be also removed from the stack, which means every time when we call this action we'll get a new instance of `Fragment`.

**Full source code:** https://github.com/dautovicharis/sos_android/tree/q_68441622

Comment: This is really interesting. Will test this out. popUpTo idea is good.

Comment: what happens when I press the back button when section 2 is loaded?

Comment: In that case back button just closes the app. If you want to go back to section one you will need to add your custom logic for back behaviour. Additionally, maybe  what you can do is that you can have new Fragment class for each section so you can just use popUpTo with popToInclusive=false.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. The only issue I have now is that there is a jank when an item in the side menu is selected. That was not there before (when it was all done manually without the navigation components)

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with what I've understood of your question: You have a single `Fragment` with different data. Now, You want to have a dynamic list (`RecyclerView`) in the `NavigationDrawer` and based on that you want to change the data list provided to the fragment `ContentFragment`. Also, you want to use NavigationGraph of which I actually don't see any purpose as you're only using a single Fragment which can be directly loaded into the `FragmentContainer`. Now, let's focus on your two points:

### **Dynamic `List` in `RecyclerView`**

1. To create a dynamic list in Drawer, place a RecyclerView in NavigationView as:

   ```
   <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:openDrawer="start">

     <!--...Other content...-->

     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start">

       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/recyclerViewDrawer"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:listitem="@layout/row_drawer" />

     </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
   </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
   ```

   You can put the `RecyclerView` in a layout as well, that's your choice.
2. Create a Layout item and adapter for the RecyclerView to populate. Basic stuff, not including.
3. Pass a list of the items to the adapter you want to show in the drawer and importantly, pass a callback which can be called when any of the item is clicked. You can set-up an interface or can pass a callback as:

   ```
    /* You can set the callback to a variable of the AdapterDrawer using the object adapter, 
    neat way, avoids crash instead of passing in constructor.*/
    val adapter = AdapterDrawer(list) 
    adapter.callback = {position: Int, item: String ->
        //This will be called whenever any item is clicked 
        //and will return the clicked position and the item text. 
    }

    //In the adapter, Create a variable as
    var callback: ((position: Int, item: String) -> Unit)? = null
    //Call in item's onClickListener as
    callback?.invoke(position, itemValue)
   ```
4. This is your first point complete - Setting up a dynamic list in `Drawer`.

---

### Creating/Re-creating the fragment from `Drawer` list's callback

1. Don't use graph property in the layout. It will be set dynamically.
2. Add the `arguments` to fragment in the graph as:

   ```
   <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/nav_classes"
     app:startDestination="@id/class_view_pager_fragment">

     <fragment
       android:id="@+id/class_view_pager_fragment"
       android:name="com.tech.cyndi.fragments.FragmentClassViewPager"
       tools:layout="@layout/activity_class">

       //to set a Model as a type, pass its whole path like com.android.app.DataModel
       <argument
         android:name="DataList"
         app:argType="com.x.x.ModelClass[]" />
     </fragment>
   </navigation>
   ```
3. Now, put the fragment creation logic in a function which will be called initially to set-up the default fragment and then, later on whenever the callback will be called. The data will then be updated based on the values returned by the `callback`.

   ```
   //You can declare and initialize the fragmentHost variable before this.
   fun setUpFragment (list: ArrayList<YourModel>) {
       val fragmentHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(binding.yourFragment.id) as NavHostFragment
       fragmentHost.navController.apply {
           val args = Bundle()
           args.putParcelableArrayList("list", list);
           setGraph(navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.yourNavGraph), args)
   }
   ```
4. Last and Final step, call this function from activity's `onCreate()` for first time and from the `callback` declared above whenever the data is changed.

Comment: I don't want to update the data in the same fragment. I want to create a new fragment instance everytime an item in the sidemenu is selected.

Comment: @500865 Then, you have to manually instantiate multiple fragments without Nav graph.